# Is this DFA correct?

Tags: automata

I am reviewing.

I need to write a DFA that accepts a string w such that bab is not a substring.

[image]

Is there any error. Also, any guideline or tips? Since it's a DFA I don't make more than 2 transition from any state and I make sure there is exactly 2 transition state from all states.

My understanding is that NFA may have more than 2 transitions for an alphabet with 2 letters and that's basically the only difference between a DFA and a NFA.

Comment: I immediately see a way to get 'bab': middle to bottom-middle (b), bottom middle to top right (a), top right to final state (b).

Comment: Actually I see lots of ways to generate 'bab'.

Comment: but if I remove the a loop from state 1, it won't be a dfa anymore, right?

Comment: Yes it would, it means you can only see a 'b' from the initial state.  That's still incorrect and doesn't fix the actual problem I pointed out.

Comment: but the "final" state is not an accepting state

Comment: You can go from the bottom-middle state to the top-left state (b), self loop to the top-left state (a), then top-left to top-middle (b).  Since the top middle is labeled as an accept state, this DFA would accept 'bbbab' (assuming the top-left is the initial state).

Comment: There _is_ an algorithm for generating an NFA for any given conditions and then inserting $\varepsilon$ transitions to convert the NFA to a DFA but I forget it and frankly, unless you are going to program a lexer there is no point in knowing it (since you can usually just figure the DFA out for yourself without it).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just reason through it.  Can the first letter be 'a' or 'b'?  Yes, so you should have two transitions coming from the initial state.  If you saw an 'a', what can you see next?  Anything right? Well this sounds like the same situation as the initial state, so loop back.  Now what if you saw a 'b' first?  Can you see a 'b' or an 'a' next?  *Yes*, you can see *both*!  What if you see a 'b'?  Then you should just start over in this state (because this was for the first 'b' you saw).  But what if you see an 'a' followed by this 'b'?  There is only one thing that can come next: 'a' to break the string 'bab'.  So the DFA should look something like [this](http://sketchtoy.com/60216134).

**Edited [DFA](http://sketchtoy.com/60216640) with properly labeled accept states, a non-accept state (with no outward transitions), and every state has exactly two transitions for 'a' or 'b'.**

Comment: but it doesn't accept bb

Comment: Actually, you can just make every state an accept state and then this should be fine.

Answer (score 1):

This is not correct. Consider $abbbab$. Similarly, I can run $abab$ and it will be accepted.

On state $q_{0}$, you can keep looping on an input of $a$. On an input of $b$, go to state $q_{1}$. Stay at $q_{1}$ on an input of $b$, and transition to state $q_{2}$ on an input of $a$. Transition from state $q_{2}$ to $q_{0}$ on an input of $a$.

For $q_{1}$ and $q_{2}$, transition to $q_{accept}$ on an input of $\epsilon$, the empty string.

In this way, you can never have $bab$ as a substring.